# Default button does not react to enter pressing on window dialog

Tags: wpf, xaml, dialog, window

I have a small user control with 'Browse' button for selecting some file and with textbox for visualization of path to selected file:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FilePath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<Button Content="Browse" cal:Message.Attach="SelectInstallationPointsFile" />
```

The control starting from window dialog as window with two buttons - `OK` and `Cancel` that defined on window resourse style (simplified version of the code):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                ...
                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" /> <!-- here will be the user control -->
                <Button IsDefault="True" Content="OK" cal:Message.Attach="Apply" />
                <Button IsCancel="True" cal:Message.Attach="Cancel" />
            ...
</Style>
```

View of dialog (green section - the window, red - the user control):

[image: green section - the window, red - the user control]

The problem is next - when you click the `Enter` button, then react the `Browse` button from user control, but not `OK` button from window dialog, although `OK` button has `IsDefault="True"`!

Comment: Have you tried with IsDefault="false" in the browse button?

Comment: Do you want to make Browse button your default button. This is bad practise i think. You should set tab indexex. If current selected item is textbox then tab will highlight browse and then press enter.

Comment: I don't have any problem when I try it.

Comment: Ramesh Muthiah, yes, I have tried...but it does not work...

Comment: Faisal Hafeez, actually i'd like to make OK button as default button. Please, read carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just tried Focusable="False" in the 'Browse' button, and it works!)

Answer (score 0):

in your YourUserControl.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class YourUserControl : UserControl
{
    public YourUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.OkBtn.Focus();
    }
}
```

sorry, my fault, can you try:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=OkBtn}">
```

?

Comment: The user control has no OK button. The OK button is the part of dialog window.